# Responsividade no WordPress - Desenvolvedor

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Estou fazendo manutenção de um site feito no WordPress. Não fui eu que desenvolvi e é primeira vez que mexo no WordPress então estou com algumas dúvidas. Como saber se foi utilizado algum plugin para responsividade ? Preciso alterar algumas coisas no celular que diferem do PC e vice-versa. De preferência gostaria de alterar codificando

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, você pode conferir se foi utilizado algum framework de uso comum para CSS/HTML responsivo. Procure no seu código referências ao Bootstrap ou Foundation. São os mais comuns do mercado.

Você também pode encontrar no CSS do seu tema atual os media-queries. Caso encontre, você pode manipular o que precisar dentro desse código!

Comment: Ok, entendi! Muit obrigado mesmo